# upgrading to spring-data 1.9

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

After upgrading spring-data from 1.8 to 1.9 I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface com.acme.util.RepositoryEx to match the given arguments: [Ljava.lang.Object;@4ef820c3
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:338)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 87 more
```

I have a simple RepositoryEx class like:

```
public interface RepositoryEx<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Sort sort, long offset, long count);


}
```

That my other repository interfaces all inherit from, is there something else I need to add?

Thanks, Jason

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem. My base repository implementation class extends `SimpleJpaRepository` and only had a constructor with the arguments `Class<T> domainClass, EntityManager em`. Adding the following constructor solved the problem for me:

```
public MyBaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
  super(entityInformation, entityManager);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! And I got this answer from https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-763